# How to delete File from SFTP while using inbound-streaming-channel-adapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp

Hi how i can delete the source file from SFTP after consuming the file . below is my configuration . Its consuming the file properly and processing it . But in the next poll its reading the same again . I like to delete the source file or avoid the same file reading again.i am using 4.3.13

```
 <int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter id="sftpAdapter"
                                  session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                                  filename-pattern="*.xml"
                                  channel="receiveChannel"
                                  remote-directory="/tmp/charge/">
</int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>

<int:poller fixed-rate="30000" max-messages-per-poll="1" id="ChargePoller"/>

<int:channel id="receiveChannel">
    <int:queue/>
</int:channel>

<int:stream-transformer id="withCharset" charset="UTF-8"    input-channel="receiveChannel" output-channel="fileInString"  />

<int:service-activator id="ChargeFeedListener" input-channel="fileInString"  method="onMessage" >
    <bean class="listener.ChargeFeedListener">
        <constructor-arg name="ChargeService" ref="ChargeService"/>
    </bean>
</int:service-activator>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<int-sftp:inbound-streaming-channel-adapter>` stores this info into headers of the message for remote file stream it produces:

```
 return getMessageBuilderFactory()
                    .withPayload(session.readRaw(remotePath))
                    .setHeader(IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE, session)
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY, file.getRemoteDirectory())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE, file.getFilename())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_HOST_PORT, session.getHostPort())
                    .setHeader(FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE_INFO,
                            this.fileInfoJson ? file.toJson() : file);
```

Pay attention to the `FileHeaders.REMOTE_DIRECTORY` and `FileHeaders.REMOTE_FILE` headers.

Such an info could used for the `<int-sftp:outbound-gateway>` with `command="rm"` as a `remote-filename-generator-expression="headers[file_remoteDirectory]+'/'+headers[file_remoteFile]"`.

This gateway could be used as a second subscriber for the `fileInString` message channel which you should make as a `<publish-subscribe-channel>`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-publishsubscribechannel.

See also this in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-streaming-java-config